# Struggling to figure out why this capacitor voltage is huge

Tags: capacitor, converter, matlab, simulink

As you can see in this image from simulations on Matlab-Simulink:

[image]

I'm tracking the blue signal (reference current) using this circuit
[image]

Which is in this 400 kV HVDC link as "Snubber".

[image]

So basically the idea is to charge and discharge this capacitor inside the snubber circuit to track the triangle reference current, but the thing is that I don't know why there's too much voltage across this capacitor. If I'm correct, the snubber will always see the difference between 12-pulse rectifier output voltage and HVDC Link voltage, and this difference should be a bit closer than 1 million volts.

Any comment on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. What voltage do you expect? What is your 3-phase AC voltage? Why do you need 2 supplies in series at the bridge rectifiers? We need some details please.

Comment: AC voltage is 200kV and I really don't know what voltage should be across the snubber, but I find it strange that it is reaching 1MV. Also, I need 2 rectifier in order to have a 12-pulse voltage at the output (secondaries at the transformer are in a Y/D config)